# Sharing TestNG setup across different test classes - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, nullpointerexception, testng

How can I share the same selenium test set up across different test classes? I keep getting nullpointexception and cannot figure out how to solve it. I've been stock in this issue for a while and searched the issue for hours but still haven't solved it. Please help.

This is my setup class

```
import static org.testng.Assert.fail;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class SettingsClass {

WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromeDriver_path");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized", "chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); // delete all cookies
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}
```

And here is my test class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.Settings;

public class ClassA extends SettingsClass {

boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    driver.get("http://www.fakeurl.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
}
```

}

---

Here is the error message I keep getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ClassA.test(ClassA.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:659)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:845)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1153)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Any advice and help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Declare WebDriver as public and static and try it once, `public static WebDriver driver;` and remove WebDriver decleration from `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` in `setUp()` method

Comment: @jay make driver object in SettingClass as public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
public class SettingsClass {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromeDriver_path");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized", "chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); // delete all cookies
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great it worked!! Thank you. I tried making it protected and it worked too. Should I keep it as public or change it to protected?

Comment: Actual change is, you have declared `WebDriver` two times (second time inside `setUp()` method). i have removed that. if it works plz accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are still problems with this approach of relying on a `@BeforeTest` to instantiate your `WebDriver` instance in a base class and have all of the test classes extend this base class (`SettingsClass` in this case) because by default a `@BeforeTest` method is designed to be involved ONLY once per `<test>` in a suite xml file. So if you have two or more such child classes of this base class (`SettingsClass` in this case) you are going to end up seeing the same `NullPointerException` in your tests i.e.,

You will see the same `NullPointerException` if you do the following:

- Create a new class named `ClassB` which also extends `SettingsClass` (and)
- Include `ClassA` and `ClassB` in the same `<test>` tag in your suite xml file.

You should instead consider moving to perhaps into a `ThreadLocal` model which would be initialized by one of the following mechanisms:

- via a `@BeforeMethod` annotated method
- via a TestNG listener such as `IInvokedMethodListener#beforeInvocation`
- via an implementation of `org.testng.IHookable` interface.

You can refer to the blog post that I created which talks about using TestNG listeners coupled with `ThreadLocal` variables to manage concurrent webdriver instances. Please see if that helps.

Blog link : https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/